# Headline meaning in WASH. POST

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

It's hard to analyze the structure of the phrases and get their sense of meaning.

WH DRAFTS MORE CLEARANCE CANCELLATIONS DEMANDED BY PRES. TRUMP, COULD BE RELEASED AS DISTRACTIONS TO UNFAVORABLE NEWS.

1. How many verbs are here
2. What is a subject which responds to "could be released~" and what is released?
3. "What is" the "unfavorable news" here ? and "To whom" the " unfavorable news" belongs?
4. What does this sentence mean?

[image]

Comment: what is your question?  You have a sentence.  And you tell us it is hard to analyze.  But you haven't asked a question.  What specifically is the problem here?

Comment: ["White House drafts more clearance cancellations demanded by Trump"](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/former-intelligence-officials-rebuke-trump-for-pulling-brennans-security-clearance/2018/08/17/ea8382f2-a20d-11e8-8e87-c869fe70a721_story.html) and the first sentence of the article rephrases the title into "**The White House** has **drafted** documents **revoking** the security **clearances** of current and former officials whom .."

Comment: I don't know what a 'clearance cancellation' is, but "The White House has drafted some more of them, as demanded by POTUS." Treat the comma as a fullstop/period here. Now, working backwards in the "headline speak": 'Unfavorable news' is probably the recently events which were widely reported. 'Distractions to' probably means 'distractions *from* [that news]'. 'Released as distractions' means 'published in order to distract from [etc]' and 'Could be ...' is surmising that this might happen.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to analyse an example of "newspaper headlinese" that would be completely opaque to most native speakers unless they were following US White House procedures / presidential politics very closely indeed.

Comment: I think this should be kept open. It does require some understanding of political reporting conventions, but nothing that an ordinary reader of routine US news would not have.

Answer (score 1):

One meaning of "draft" is to write something for review and criticism before official publication. That is the meaning here: people in the White House are writing documents for Trump to review and approve or disapprove.

"Clearance cancellation" requires knowing something about procedures of the U.S. government. People  who are legally authorized to learn about secret information relative to military, foreign policy, and security matters are given "security clearances." Many people who previously held senior positions in the U.S. government are permitted to keep their security clearances after leaving office, but this privilege is granted subject to the continued approval of the president. So "clearance cancellations" are notices that it is now a crime to let a person who formerly had a security clearance know such information.

The final "could be released" is an implication that the cancellations are for a purpose that the Post views as illegitimate.